# Edit 'Welcome Mr xyz' message on Contribution Form

Tags: contribution-page

My Contribution Pages have a message at the top saying, roughly, 'Welcome Mr so and so.  To complete this form on behalf of someone else Click Here.'

A few weeks ago I edited this massage, but now I want to do so again and CAN'T FIND IT ANYWHERE.

Can anyone please direct me to where I can edit this message?

Thank you.

Comment: You may have used Word Replacement?

Comment: Good thought Pete, but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too obvious - I hadn't edited the source, just added some CSS to apply 'display:none' to the 'a' tag.

Thanks for the other suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the "Welcome Mr X (Not Mr X, or want to do this for a different person?)" message.  That text is in `templates/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution/Main.tpl`

It is possible to override templates - see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/templates/customizing/ for details.  As the documentation warns, there are problems associated with doing this.